# ruby in 100 minutes good_morning method issue

Tags: ruby, constants, irb, initialization

I have been doing the Ruby in 100 minutes  on the JumpStart labs website, and encountered a problem during part 5.

I was asked to create a good_morning method that would print out a greeting such as 'Happy Monday, it's the 130 day of 2013'. Here is my current program:

```
class PersonalChef

    def good_morning

        today = Date.today.strftime("%A")
        day_of_year = Date.today.yday
        puts "Happy#{today}! It is the #{day_of_year} day of year."
        return self
            end

    def make_toast(color)
        puts " Making your toast #{color}!"
        return self
       end
    def make_milkshake(flavor)
        puts " Making a #{flavor} milkshake!"
        return self
       end

    def make_eggs(quantity)
        puts " Making you #{quantity} eggs!"
        return self
            end 
            end
```

when I try to run the program load on irb( 'personal_chef.rb', frank = PersonalChef.new, frank.make_milkshake('chocolate'), etc, everything works fine until I try to type frank.good_morning into irb, which gives the following error message:

```
NameError: **uninitialized constant** PersonalChef :: Date 
     from personal_chef.rb:5: in good_morning from (irb):3 from /bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
```

Any help or information to help me solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've highlighted the important part of the error message for you.

Comment: Wow that was fast. I am fairly new to this, so I don't know exactly what that means... how to initialize a constant?

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you haven't required the 'date' library.  So when your code executes the good_morning method it doesn't know about Ruby's Date class.  So in that scope it tries to find a PersonalChef::Date class which also doesn't exist.

Add the following to the top of the file and it should work:

```
require 'date'
```